# Python, tkinter, subprocess.Popen, raw_input() and stdin

Tags: tkinter

Old C programmer but new to Python.

I am working on a GUI (using tkinter) that launches another python file via subprocess.Popen(file). This subprocess uses raw_input() to get data from the user. In the GUI, I have a text box and have redirected stdout from the subprocess (print statements) which is fine. But I cannot find a way to enable the user to enter data in the GUI text box window (like stdin=PIPE) - everything hangs or just fails.

Prior to redirecting stdout, all i/o was done in the terminal (shell) window which was 'OK' except the user had to switch from the GUI to the terminal window... back and forth.

My question then: is there a way to obtain user input to the subprocess raw_input() statement from the GUI text box? I cannot find an answer.

Thanks!

Mark

> > > edit... small example added <<<
> > > new here so forgive me if I did this incorrectly! <<<

````py
import os
from Tkinter import *
import ScrolledText as tkst
import subprocess

#create root window
root = Tk()
root.title('GUI Subprocess Test')
root.geometry("1200x800")

def startMain(): #
    
    #lauch a subprocess
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "getname.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    # proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "getname.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

    #clear the text box widget
    text.delete("1.0", END)
    
    #send the scripts output to the GUI text box
    for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline,''):
        text.insert(END, line)
        #update in "real time"
        text.see(END)
        text.update_idletasks()

#Start Button
submitButton = Button(root, text = "     START     ", command = startMain)
submitButton.grid(row = 4, column = 2, padx = (30,20), pady = (40,0))

#Text widget
text = tkst.ScrolledText(root, width=120)
text.place(x=100, y=150)
        
root.mainloop()

```python subprocess
import sys
import math

print "Filename: ", sys.argv[0]

print "Pi = ", math.pi

for x in range(1,11):
    print (x, "* pi = ", math.pi * x)

sys.stdout.flush()

name = raw_input ("Name please: ")

print ("Nice to meet you, " + name)

``` END OF EXAMPLE CODE
````

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: My originals are quite large. Will have to create small example, maybe tomorrow.

Comment: Like I said, we want a [mcve]. We don't need or want the full original code.

Comment: To be clear, these are 2 separate files. The 1st is the GUI and the 2nd (get_name.py) is the spawned subprocess. Works up until the raw_input() function. (if you enter 'name' in the cmd.exe window, it's 'OK'... barely. the prompt shows up after the fact!) If you use the line w/stdin=PIPE, it hangs.